# Product form not loaded in magento2

Tags: magento2, product

I am adding 2 custom attribute when product is virtual.

But when i checking my downloadable product all other attributes are not display excepting images and videos.

Can anyone help?

[image]

**Getting below error in console:**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return label }"
>   Message: label is not defined
>       at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), :3:55)
>       at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3989)
>       at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
>       at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
>       at init (knockout.js:3988)
>       at knockout.js:2989
>       at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
>       at knockout.js:2988
>       at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)

Comment: Can you check browser console if there is any error or not?

Comment: @SukumarGorai yes getting below error in console